# Calling a Task.Builder function in F#

Tags: f#

```
         | Log (message, ack) ->

         let CreateEventSourcingConnection() =
             task {
                 let connection =
                     let ipEndPoint = IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 1113)
                     EventStoreConnection.Create(ipEndPoint)
                 do! connection.ConnectAsync()
                 return connection
             }

         let connectionM = CreateEventSourcingConnection ()

         let AddEventToStreamAsync (connection: IEventStoreConnection) streamName eventName message =
             task {
                 let serializedEventData =
                     message
                     |> JsonConvert.SerializeObject
                     |> Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes
                 let event = EventData(Guid.NewGuid(), eventName, true, serializedEventData, null)

                 let! _ = connection.AppendToStreamAsync(streamName, int64 ExpectedVersion.Any, event)
                 ()
             }
         AddEventToStreamAsync connectionM "a" "a"
```

The line

```
AddEventToStreamAsync connectionM "a" "a"
```

Produces this error

> The type 'Task' is not compatible with the type 'IEventStoreConnection'

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do `let!` on the `Task` that is returned from `CreateEventSourcingConnection`, before passing it to `AddEventToStreamAsync`, one way would be to change the signature to take a task then `let!` on it inside, like this:

```
let AddEventToStreamAsync (connectionTask: Task<IEventStoreConnection>) streamName eventName message =
    task {
        let serializedEventData =
            message
            |> JsonConvert.SerializeObject
            |> Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes
        let event = EventData(Guid.NewGuid(), eventName, true, serializedEventData, null)

        let! connection = connectionTask
        let! _ = connection.AppendToStreamAsync(streamName, int64 ExpectedVersion.Any, event)
        ()
    }

AddEventToStreamAsync connectionM "a" "a"
```